# Organization Chart set default account

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, cumulative-update, organization-browser

after updating on CU January 2017 (SharePoint 2013) it is not possible any more to set the default account for the org Chart on a subsite.

[January 10, 2017, update for SharePoint Server 2013 (KB3141477)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3141477/january-10,-2017,-update-for-sharepoint-server-2013-kb3141477)

seems that they modified something according to the org browser.

This is the code that worked before to Setup the Default account:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CreateHierarchyChartControl(parentId, profileId, type, persistControlId) {
  var i = profileId.indexOf("|");
  var claimsmode = profileId.substr(i-1,1);
  if((i >=0 ) & (claimsmode=="w"))
  {
  profileId = "Domain\user"; //******
   var initParam = profileId + ',' + type + ',' + persistControlId;
   var host = document.getElementById(parentId);
   host.setAttribute('width', '100%');
   host.setAttribute('height', '100%');
   Silverlight.createObject('/_layouts/ClientBin/hierarchychart.xap',
    host,
    'ProfileBrowserSilverlightControl',
    {
     top: '30',
     width: '100%',
     height: '100%',
     version: '2.0',
     isWindowless: 'true',
     enableHtmlAccess: 'true'
    },
    {
     onLoad: OnHierarchyChartLoaded
    },
     initParam,
     null);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Any suggestion how to fix it?